# Union of DF: OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 10GB CSV file in storage account.

I try to call the HTTP GET and get the contents in byte range for e.g. in first loop, get 0 to 500MB then 501MB-1000MB etc.

Below code works fine if I comment Union of DF part. How can I write it differently to solve this error?

It exactly fails in 5th loop, I guess after processing (500MB x 4 loops) 2GB (which is some heap space which is crossed)

```
for(i <- 1 to chunkNum) {
  
  println(i)
          // Hiding unnecessary code to get data in ranges
          val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
          val currentDate = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance.getTime)
          println("BeforeResponse")
          val response =  GetHttpResponse(headers, "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/test/traindata.csv")
          println("AfterResponse")
          dfRestAPI = dfRestAPI.union(Seq((response,currentDate)).toDF("Chunk","InsertedDate")) 
       
        }
```

Comment: Compression could easily achieve the desired size. However how?

Comment: Just download and partition the data chunk-by-chunk, you don't need spark for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using REST API to fetch data, just allow Spark to do its job automatically - if the CSV file isn't compressed, then Spark should automatically split it into chunks (here is more [details](https://garrens.com/blog/2017/10/09/spark-file-format-showdown-csv-vs-json-vs-parquet/)) and process in parallel from the multiple workers.

In your case, you're trashing the Java virtual memory with big chunks, that most probably aren't garbage collected yet.

Comment: Sorry, we need to achieve this only using Rest API. To authenticate the storage account, we have to generate token, use that token, call GET Blob (Rest API), store the data in DF and later use it. Any other workarounds? Like flush out memory, save data in different DFs?

Comment: read data, append data into file(s) on DBFS of your workspace, and then read from it. Also, your code is executed only in the context of the driver node, efficiently single-threaded

Comment: The GetHttpResponse has something wrong. It is somehow keep on adding up data in memory. Appreciate if you can take a look at another question which has the actual root cause - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200457/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-receiving-http-response

Comment: As you said, I am trying to implement the logic that you said - read http and save data but want to do that in a function that's available in different post that I mentioned in earilier comment